# $K$ is a linear compact operator on Hilbert space $H$. Will the image of $I-K$ on every closed subspace of $H$ be also closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory, compact-operators

Just as the title. We know the image of $I-K$ is closed, but if we restrict $H$ to a closed subspace $V$, will $(I-K)(V)$ be a closed subspace of $H$? Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $V\subset H$ is closed then, $I-K$ restricted to $V$, still being a proper map.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what "still being a proper map" means in your hint.

Comment: @Martin, take a sequence $y_n=(I-K)x_n$ in $(I-K)(V)$ converging to some $y\in H$. Then the set $\{y_n\}_n\cup\{y\}$ is compact. Because $I-K$ restricted to $V$ is proper, you have that the set $\{x_n\}_n\cup\{(I-K)^{-1}{y}\}$ is compact.

Comment: I see. I was asking about the meaning of proper, but it is clear now. Thanks